# Update SWIFTUI text font size with slider?

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I am trying to update font size but using user interaction with slider object.
But using below code is not updating font as texts are not updating on changed value.

`@State var fontSize: CGFloat = 14.0`

```
 HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 20) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(viewModel.isSelectionStarted ? viewModel.verseModels[viewModel.selectedFrameworkIndex1 ].English: "")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .font(.system(size: CGFloat(fontSize)))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)



                            Text(viewModel.isSelectionStarted ? viewModel.verseModels[viewModel.selectedFrameworkIndex1 ].Spanish: "")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .font(.system(size: CGFloat(fontSize)))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
```

Slider code:

```
Slider(value: $fontSize, in: 6...32, step: 1)
                        .padding()
                        .accentColor(Color.green)
                        .border(Color(hex: "#066892"), width: 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the order of the Text functions:

```
.font(.subheadline)
.font(.system(size: CGFloat(fontSize)))
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
```

To:

```
.font(.system(size: CGFloat(fontSize)))
.font(.subheadline)
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
```

Should work.

Comment: When you first call .font(.subheadline) and then .font(.system(size: CGFloat(fontSize))), the last Text instance returned to your Text will be .font(.subheadline). This overrides your .font(.system(size: CGFloat(fontSize))) size. Glad I could help ;)